# Why does String class would augment from Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the book `JavaScript the good parts` and saw following code:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
 this.prototype[name] = func;
 return this;
};

String.method('trim', function ( ) {
 return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
});
document.writeln('"' + " neat ".trim( ) + '"');
```

What confuses my is that, in `Function.prototype.method` definition, it simply augments the `prototype` property of Function class, and should have nothing to do with `Object.prototype`. So why in that case `String` object would still have the `method` method?

Comment: you are calling it from String(), so String==this...

Comment: That `Function.prototype.method` is a pretty silly shorthand.

Comment: @MattBall: Especially in beginner books…

Comment: @MattBall Why is it silly?

Comment: It's just plain unnecessary. It doesn't make your code more concise, just less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because constructors are functions, so `String` is a function with a `prototype`. The `Function.prototype.method` lets you add a method to the prototype any function, in this case `String`.

Comment: Why can't we simply use `this[name] = func`' but have to use `this.prototype[name] = func`?

Comment: @OneZero: the first defines static methods, the second defines inherited methods.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, let's first see what `String` is:

```
> typeof String
"function"
```

It's a function, so anything defined on `Function.prototype` are "inherited"; so let's look at what `method()` does:

```
this.prototype[name] = func;
```

Here, `this.prototype` refers to `String.prototype` and thus, this code really does:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() { ... }
```

Comment: WTH do you mean with that "auto-boxing"? As it stands, it sounds wrong. String literals are not passed to the `String` function.

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't really contribute to the answer anyway, so I've gotten rid of it.